# Why can I represent an int larger than MAXINT in hexadecimal, but not decimal?

Tags: c, int, hex, decimal

As far as I am aware, decimal and hexadecimal are simply representations of  (let's say) an `int`.

This means that if I define an integer, `x` I should be able to print `x` as:

- a decimal: `printf("%d", x);`
- a hexadecimal: `printf("%x", x);`

What I don't understand is how this behaves when `x` exceeds MAXINT.

Take the below code for example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // Define two numbers that are both less than MAXINT
    int a =  808548400;
    int b = 2016424312;

    int theSum = a + b; // 2824972712 -> larger than MAXINT

    printf("%d\n", theSum); // -1469994584 -> Overflowed
    printf("%x\n", theSum); // A861A9A8 -> Correct representation

}
```

As my comments suggest, the sum of these two decimal numbers is a number larger than MAXINT. This number has overflowed when printed as a decimal (as I would expect), but when printed as hexadecimal it appears to be perfectly fine.

Interestingly, if I continue adding to this number, and cause it to overflow again, it returns to representing the decimal number correctly. The hexadecimal number is always correct.

Could anyone explain why this is the case.

TIA

Comment: Because `%x` handles the number as an **unsigned** int.

Comment: `%x` is a format specifier for *unsigned* `int`. So technically using it with signed one which is not fitting into unsigned is undefined behavior.

Comment: Well what are we calling "larger" in the first place. -1469994584 is also unsigned-larger than INT_MAX and you also compared the hexadecimal result as if unsigned.

Comment: I hope someone writes a full answer instead of comments. OP is already confused; short comments only make it more confusing.

Comment: Fair enough. Agreed.

Comment: So would I not expect the compiler to report a warning here if `%x` is specifically for an unsigned int when the variable is declared as a signed int?

Comment: @mbamber warnings are not specified by C. For a compiler, this means *analyzing* the format string. Eg `gcc` can do this, although I'm not sure there will be a warning in that specific case. Try options `-std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Citing n1570 (latest C11 draft), **§7.21.6.1 p8**:

> [...]
>   **o,u,x,X** The `unsigned int` argument is converted to unsigned octal (**o**), unsigned
>   decimal (**u**), or unsigned hexadecimal notation (**x** or **X**) [...]

So, in a nutshell, you're using a conversion specifier for the **wrong type** here. Actually, your signed overflow is **undefined behavior**, but your implementation obviously uses 2's complement for negative numbers and the overflow results in a *wraparound* on your system, so the result is exactly the same representation as the correct **unsigned** number.

If you used `%u` instead of `%x`, you would see the same number in decimal notation. Again, this would be the result of **undefined behavior** that *happens* to be "correct" on your system. Always avoid signed overflows, the result is allowed to be *anything*.

Comment: So does this mean the hex representation is correct 'by chance' because of the implementation on my machine?

Comment: @mbamber yes. **most** machines/implementations behave this way, 2's complement and wraparound on signed overflow are **very** common. But C doesn't guarantee that, so you can't do something like this in *portable* code. There are machines where the result will be different.