# Depiction of binary digit changes during promotion from signed to unsigned integers/what happens?

Tags: c, operators, bitwise-operators, unsigned-integer

y is promoted to unsigned int and compared with x here.Does binary number comparison happen everytime? Then if(12 == -4) is done, why can't it promote LHS to unsigned and print "same"?(considering 12 = 1100, -4 = 1100)Please correct if I am wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    unsigned int x = -1;
    int y = ~0;
    if(x == y)//1.what happens if( y == x) is given?.O/P is "same" then also.
        printf("same");//output is "same"
    else
        printf("not same");
    printf("%d",x);//2.output is -1.Won't x lose it's sign when unsigned is given?My hunch is x should become +1 here. 
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Please also provide the binary number working for the above code and answers to 1. and 2. in the code comments.Thank you.

Comment: The `why can't it promote LHS to 4 and print "same"` part of your question is extremely unclear IMO.

Comment: sorry.forgot to change it.one moment.

Comment: And BTW, `-4 == 1100` only on 4-bit systems.

Comment: `printf("%d",x);` is undefined behavior as `x` is not an `int`.

Comment: *Please provide the answers to my homework in the code comments* isn't going to work out well for you here.

Comment: Is it so @NathanOliver? when you print y using %d also it shows -1. It proves that x and y are equal by bits.

Comment: with `%d`, you tell `printf()` it's *signed*. So `printf()` believes you.

Comment: [somewhat related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45865826/2371524)

Comment: Nit: "promotion" doesn't change values. What you have is "conversion".

Comment: In general, none of these questions make sense **in terms of C**. The representation of negative numbers is *implementation defined*. Converting `-1` to an unsigned type is guaranteed to give you the maximum value, but that's about it. Printing an `unsigned` with `%d` is **undefined behavior**, as already stated.

Comment: I think I would be clear if someone just provided the binary values of x and y at each stage of the code. forget the %d printf() for x. If x is unsigned, what is the decimal equivalent of -1 at x?

Comment: Do not worry guys - it is the "beginners hack" id comes back here literally every day. Let hin play with it. Everyone has passed this time - learned some C and suddenly started to notice how many errors the compiler has :) in more extreme form the post has a title like "output not as expected" and loooong  compiled assembly listing showing errors in the compiler

Comment: if(12 == -4) what do you think about that?

Answer (score -1):

First check in your system for size of `unsigned int`.

in my machine: `printf("%zu\n",sizeof(unsigned int));//4 byte`

as we have 4 bytes to store an Uint data type, we can say

`unsigned int x ;//`

`x:Range[0, Max_number_with_4byte]`

`Max_number_with_4byte:   (2^32) - 1 = 0xFFFFFFFF`

obviously x can hold only positive numbers because of unsigned.

but you give to `x = -1;`, suppose a circular behaviour, when we put back one step from `0`, x reach to last point: Max_number_with_4byte.

and printing x to screen shows: `0xFFFFFFFF`

see hex equivalent of x with `printf("%x\n",(unsigned int )x);`
and  `printf("%y\n",(unsigned int )y);` to see equality of x,y.

consider `y = ~0;` we have 32 bits for y if ~ operator use in y all bits are changes to 1, in hex form we see `FFFFFFFF`. (we cant print binary numbers with printf and use equal hex representation)

you can see this [online calculator](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_signed_int.html?decimal=045049) how to convert `-1` to `0xFFFFFFFF`

Answer to your Question

`y` is not promoted to unsigned int. it is just changes its bits form `0 -> 1`

Does binary number comparison happen every time?

Yes in every conditions for example in `if(10 > 20)` first both 10 and 20 converted to its correspondent binary numbers then compare.

`if (12 == -4)` see my above explanation.

`-4` not equals to  `1100` inside computer (your variable).

`-4 = 0xFFFFFFFC`  [see](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_signed_int.html?decimal=045052)

Answer (score -2):

An unsigned int =-1 should actually interpreted as the max unsigned int(4294967295); surely is not transformed into 1.